# Saving all x and y points from mousedragged

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have this where I drag my mouse and it basically paints in the shape of small ovals or rectangles, but I'm unsure of how to make it save all of the points to repaint them when the window is resized... I know it has something to do with paintComponent() but not quite sure how to go about doing it, any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the bit that does the drawing

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
        Point pt = evt.getPoint();
        x = pt.x;
        y = pt.y;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        if(Shape == "Oval"){
            g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
            }
        if(Shape == "Rectangle"){
            g.drawRect(x, y, 10, 10);
            } 
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    }
```

Comment: That saves them nice, but how would I call them in the paintComponent method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list (external to your method) that stores all the points.

```
List<Point> list = new LinkedList<>() ;
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
    Point pt = evt.getPoint();
    list.add(pt) ;
```

Comment: Why do you use a LinkedList?

Comment: @AlexWien Assuming points are only iterated over and not needed to be accessed by index, it does really matter. OP just needs some collection.

Comment: Because he doesn't have any idea of the number of point to expect, and they are going to be read only once. So I wanted to minimize the risk of reallocation, because the reading part occurs only once. Is that wrong?

Comment: I can can print the (x,y) fine but I'm having trouble actually getting them to integers and using them in redrawing

Comment: Getting them in integers? Do you mean a "cast"? Then `int x=(int)(list.get(i).x+0.5);`

Comment: Ya, that's what I wanted, but it still is not working fully.
it repaints after resizing only if I drag the mouse again, I need it to repaint it immediately after resizing the window.

This is what I have currently: http://pastebin.com/jbVg2heu

Sorry, I'm still quite new to Java and programming in general.

Comment: The LinkdList uses more space, since it has a next pointer. I would have used an ArrayList, however in this situation it doesnt matter.